# vagrant box copy not working well

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I cannot boot a vagrant box copy without problem.

I use "hashicorp/precise32" (I cannot install "ubuntu/trusty64" or 32 on my machine, I've tried everything. I guess it's because my pc is too old, 2009).

I can `vagrant up` using the default added box "hashicorp/precise32".

All works fine.

Then, I `vagrant halt` and do a copy of the vagrant box like that :

```
vagrant package --base myprojectvm_default_1437507203066_25705 --output mybox.box

vagrant box add mybox.box --name mybox
```

Then I `vagrant destroy`.

Then I change Vagrantfile : `config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"`
to `config.vm.box = "mybox"`

THen I run `vagrant up` and I see this in my guest after minutes :

"Waiting for network configuration...
Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration....
Booting system without full network configuration..."

Then some "Starting..." lines among other lines... and finally, machine booted.

Why "without full network configuration" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the *vagrant book*

> It is very common for Linux-based boxes to fail to boot initially.
> This is often a very confusing experience because it is unclear why it
> is happening. The most common case is because there are persistent
> network device udev rules in place that need to be reset for the new
> virtual machine. To avoid this issue, remove all the persistent-net
> rules. On Ubuntu, these are the steps necessary to do this:
>
> ```
> $ rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules 
> $ mkdir /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules 
> $ rm -rf /dev/.udev/
> $ rm /lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules>
> ```

on centos box, this is the command I am running

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
sudo rm -f ifcfg-eth1

cd /etc/udev/rules.d/
sudo rm -f 70-persistent-net.rules
```

It then has always been working fine for me

Comment: Thanks but I'm sorry it won't work for me : In my vm, I have no "etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/" directory, and "/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules" is an empty directory.

Comment: Editing with steps for ubuntu as it is the os used in this case. sorry about that!

Comment: OK now I have a new problem. I can go in my vm with virtual box, but vagrant up keep showing "default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...".   Why ?!? And how to fix this ?

Comment: Did that and now can login  : wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub -O .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R vagrant:vagrant .ssh   . But what did I needed to do that ?

Comment: @trogne, you do that to make sure vagrant can login you with `vagrant ssh` command without prompt for a password. this is weird you had to do because it should have been done in the original box - if this answer helped, make sure to mark as accepted and/or vote up, thanks

Comment: @FredericHenri Do you do this as part of the provisioning of the box, or manually after boot?

Comment: @Johann no this is something you do only once before you want to run `vagrant package`